# Feed Forward Neural Network Always outputs Random but Similar Values

Tags: python, neural-network, feed-forward

I recently coded a neural network based on [this](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) online book and Sebastian Lague's brief series on neural networks on youtube. I coded it as faithfully to the original as possible but it didn't end up working. I am trying to solve a simple XOR problem with it but it always seems to give me random but similar values. I even tried copying and pasting the author's code, without changing anything, but it still didn't work.

```
class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, layer_sizes, rate):
        weight_shapes = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(layer_sizes[1:], layer_sizes[:-1])]
        self.weights = [np.random.standard_normal(s)/s[1]**0.5 for s in weight_shapes]
        self.biases = [np.zeros((s,1)) for s in layer_sizes[1:]]
        self.rate = rate

    def predict(self, a):
        for w,b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
            z = np.matmul(w,a) + b
            a = self.activation(z)
        return a

    def backprop(self, a, o):

        o = np.array(o)

        self.zCollection = []

        # Forward Propogation
        for w,b in zip(self.weights, self.biases):
            z = np.matmul(w,a) + b

            self.zCollection.append(z)

            a = self.activation(z)
        
        # Output error
        error =  (a - o) * self.activationPrime(self.zCollection[-1])

        self.weights[-1] += np.matmul(error, self.activation(self.zCollection[-2]).T) * self.rate
        self.biases[-1] += error * self.rate
        
        # Looping through layers
        for i in range(2, len(self.weights)):

            error = np.multiply(self.weights[-i+1].T * error,self.activationPrime(self.zCollection[-i]))

            self.weights[-i] = np.add(self.weights[-i], np.matmul(error, self.activation(self.zCollection[-i-1]).T) * self.rate)
            self.biases[-i] = np.add(self.biases[-i], error * self.rate)

    @staticmethod
    def activation(x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    @staticmethod
    def activationPrime(x):
        activation = lambda x : 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
        return activation(x) * (1 - activation(x))



if __name__ == "__main__":

    inp = [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
    out = [[0],[1],[1],[0]]

    # Reformating arrays
    inp = np.array([np.array(i) for i in inp])
    inp = np.array([i.reshape((len(i), 1)) for i in inp])
    out = np.array([np.array(i) for i in out])
    out = np.array([i.reshape((len(i), 1)) for i in out])


    layer_sizes = (2,2,1)
    nn = NeuralNetwork(layer_sizes, 0.001)

    print("start")
    for j in range(100):
        for i,o in zip(inp, out):
            nn.backprop(i, o)
    print("done")

    for i in inp:
        print(f"{[list(j) for j in i]} >> {nn.predict(i)[0,0]}")
```

I did some investigating myself and found that the update values for the weights were always small and constant for every iteration. I am not sure why but it looked like the weights weren't changing. I believe this may be the cause because when I set the seed at the beginning of the script the output values were incredibly similar to about 4dp, but i'm not sure. I tested the forward propagation so that cannot be the issue. I also tried randomizing the inputs, changing the learning rates, different layer sizes, and amounts. I also tried a different problem set which a perceptron could solve. That problem was to predict whether the sum of two numbers were greater than some other number. That didn't work either. When I graphed the output error over the epochs it looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXoLE.png). As you can see by the thick line the value is oscillating and seemingly decreasing. However, when I tested it it gave completely wrong results.

Here are some outputs that I am getting with different parameters:

learning rate : 100
layer_sizes : (2,2,1)
epochs : 10000

```
[[0], [0]] >> 1.70366026492168e-23
[[1], [0]] >> 4.876567289343432e-20
[[0], [1]] >> 2.4579325136292694e-24
[[1], [1]] >> 9.206132845755066e-21
```

learning rate : 1
layer_sizes : (2,5,5,1)
epochs : 10000

```
[[0], [0]] >> 0.9719657241512317
[[1], [0]] >> 0.9724187979341556
[[0], [1]] >> 0.9736236543859843
[[1], [1]] >> 0.9739884707274225
```

learning rate : 1
layer_sizes : (2,2,1)
epochs : 100

```
[[0], [0]] >> 0.3912836914268991
[[1], [0]] >> 0.49042088270977163
[[0], [1]] >> 0.4499482050352108
[[1], [1]] >> 0.5324205501065111
```

Comment: Try using MSE in the error function: `((a - o) ** 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it. I made three main changes:

1. I switched the a and o in the output layer error calculation which then looked like this: `error =  (o - a) * self.activationPrime( self.zCollection[-1] )`.
2. When updating the weights and biases I replaced

   ```
   self.weights[-1] += np.matmul(error, self.activation(self.zCollection[-2]).T) * self.rate
   self.biases[-1] += error * self.rate
   ```

   with

   ```
   self.weights[-1] = np.add(self.weights[-1], np.matmul(error, self.activation(self.zCollection[-2]).T) * self.rate)
   self.biases[-1] = np.add(self.biases[-1], error * self.rate)
   ```

   I did the same within the for loop. To see that code reference the code in the post.
3. These changes did not work with a small number of epochs though so I increased them to 100000 which worked. However, when decreasing the learning rate I had to increase the number of epochs again.

With these new parameters and changes I got the following example:

learning rate : 1
layer_sizes : (2,2,1)
epochs : 100000

```
[[0], [0]] >> 0.0024879823892047168
[[1], [0]] >> 0.9970151468472171
[[0], [1]] >> 0.996966687356631
[[1], [1]] >> 0.003029227917616288
```

I am pretty sure that these issues (if you can even call them that) have nothing to do with my code but are just a trait of feed-forward neural networks.

It took me a while but a found a 4th issue in the algorithm. In the 2nd for loop within the backprop method the `error` calculation is incorrect. The line should actually read `error = np.multiply(np.matmul(self.weights[-i+1].T, error), self.activationPrime(self.zCollection[-i]))`